# Is there a way to configure CloudFlare to ignore DDOS prevention on a specific routes/URL?

Tags: ajax, nginx, cloudflare, ddos

[image]

I have a production site that hosted behind Cloudflare.
There is a page of my application that I made 10,000 of ajax requests somehow it stopped by Cloudflare.

I get

[image]

I want to ignore this route

```
/products/flat/reindex_sub
```

Is there a way to configure Cloudflare to ignore DDOS prevention on a specific routes/URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Add a Page Rule

```
https://www.your-site.com/products/flat/reindex_sub
```

**Disable Security**

---

I hope this helps someone in the future.